# Editable block: CMS or PHP script?

Tags: php, cms

I'm designing a Website for a restaurant. The site will be fairly static except for a 'specials' block which the client will need to update on a daily basis. I'm more of a designer/front-end developer so I was wondering if I was better off trying to make a block editable in PHP (a language I hardly ever deal with) or just create the website in a user-friendly CMS such as Wordpress (which I have some experience with) or Expression Engine (which I have no experience with but I'm told is a favorite in the design community)... certainly not Drupal, because even though I have theming experience with it, I think it would be a little overkill for just one editable block in a five-page site.

I'm leaning towards an easy to use CMS because I'm really just not comfortable writing my own PHP especially since I guess a PHP solution would also require an authentication solution so only the client could get in to edit their info. Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem here is that every CMS, in this case, is an overkill.

If you were an experienced PHP programmer, to write the code you need, would require about 1 hour (more or less). Anyway, as you asserts, you aren't. Thus, you should use a CMS also because this choise will pay in the long run. What if the customer starts to call you every week to update the content? Using a CMS from the beginning, will allow you have great flexibility and avoid the possible problem to manage the change of the whole website. The latter often create problems in terms of SEO because you'll have to do several tasks to keep the good SEO efforts you, or your client, spent on the website (at least if this efforts are been spent).

Comment: Appreciate your reply, Aurelio, do you have any CMS recommendations in particular?

Comment: @Jane I'm glad to help you. I've experience using Joomla and I've never got big problems. Besides, Joomla has a large support community. Anyway you can use the CMS you like the most as Wordpress, Drupal (but you said no), Orchard and much more. Here is a list of CMS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems

Answer (score 0):

The PHP required is fairly simple and you can find examples of login scripts around many places. This would be the easiest way to implement it since it would avoid the overhead of a CMS, certainly overkill for your needs. I did something like this using ASP.NET and it was quite simple to implement.

I've done something like this with WordPress but that was for a site where there would more than one page updated from time to time. There were about 100 pages for the whole site so it made more sense there than it would for a 5 pager.

Another option would be for them to edit a text file locally and upload it to the site via FTP. You could then use a script to include it into your pre-existing page.